# How can I make a single slider that changes the color of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, slider

I'm making a 2D Unity character customization screen. I want the player to be able to change the character's hair color, and I want the color options to be practically infinite. I believe the cleanest way to execute this would be to create a slider that holds the color wheel. How can I do this?

I've tried googling and watching videos, but I am still lost.

My expected result is that the hair color changes based on the slider's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so color inside computers are traditionally RGB values. (Red Green Blue)
To change colors inside games I usually see 3 sliders, one for each value.
Each slider will be a value from 0-255. You can set that value to the amount of red, green, or blue in the hair.

To change color in code it will look something like this. I am positive there is a better way to do this, but this is something that I believe should work after watching a short Brakeys video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ8Tttcksu4

```
public float red;
public float green;
public float blue;
public float maxColor = 255;
public Color hairColor;
```

Then when your slider changes, update the hair color with a function.

```
public void UpdateRed(float newRed)
{
    red = newRed;
    UpdateHairColor();
}
public void UpdateGreen(float newGreen)
{
    green = newGreen;
    UpdateHairColor();
}
public void UpdateBlue(float newBlue)
{
    blue = newBlue;
    UpdateHairColor();
}


public void UpdateHairColor()
{
     hairColor = new Color(red/maxColor, green/maxColor, blue/maxColor);
}
```